# linked maps not working in R

Tags: r, maps

I am trying use the micromap package in R, but something is not working. This is the code:

```
library(micromap)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

setwd ('C:/Users/Jesus/Dropbox/linked maps/Chapter4')
mexico<-readShapePoly("ESTADOS.shp")
gdp<-read.csv('mexico.csv')
gdp$CVE_ENT<-as.character(gdp$CVE_ENT)
statePolys <- create_map_table(mexico, 'CVE_ENT')

lmplot(stat.data=gdp,         
       map.data=statePolys,
       panel.types=c('labels','dot','map'),
       panel.data=list('estado','percapita', NA),
       ord.by='percapita',
       grouping=8, median.row=FALSE,
       map.link=c('CVE_ENT','ID'))
```

The code seems to work but produces the the following image with incomplete information:

[image]

As you can see in the image some states are not ploted. Any idea on why my code is not working?

The link to the files is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/idvi1nlxq3uml3h/mexico.rar

Thanks,

Comment: I've checked the geometry, fixed topology problems & even simplified the spatial file by a factor of 20, but cannot get the code to work on this side either. I notice that even some of the __example__ code for micromap isn't working for me - wondering if something is broken in the dependencies?

Comment: I tried with a different shapefile file available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gncr2bkpifoq1a4/mexstates.zip And it got a little bit better. For the new file the id field is no longer CVE_ENT but ADMIN_NAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with the code was that the id field for the shape file and for the csv file were defined as character (Thanks to Mark Weber for this observation). The new code is:

```
library(micromap)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

setwd ('C:/Users/Jesus/Dropbox/linked maps/Chapter4')

mexico<-readShapePoly("mexstates.shp")

gdp<-read.csv('mexico.csv')
gdp$CVE_ENT<-as.numeric(gdp$CVE_ENT)
mexico$CVE_ENT<-as.numeric(mexico$CVE_ENT)
statePolys <- create_map_table(mexico, 'CVE_ENT')

lmplot(stat.data=gdp,         
       map.data=statePolys,
       panel.types=c('labels','dot','map'),
       panel.data=list('estado','growthgdp', NA),
       ord.by='growthgdp',rev.ord=T,
       grouping=8, median.row=FALSE,
       map.link=c('CVE_ENT','ID'))
```

and this is the result:
[image]